# PHP or jQuery/PHP pagination

Tags: php, jquery, seo, paging

I have a prewritten PHP class which I wrote for paging. This works well, but as I am moving more to combine my site with jQuery and PHP, I feel the urge to do paging with a combination of PHP and jQuery ajax calls.

My question, or concerns are, and any useful feedback would greatly be appreciated, is:

a) With the basic assumption that if I use jQuery, I will no longer have example products.php?page=2, but just products.php as jQuery will pull in the content using ajax, so no page reloads, BUT does SEO not require actual URL's to the pages? How would Google index the results?

b) Reading only there are 2 types of tutorials. One where all content is gathered from the server using PHP and then "categorised" into pages, making the paging practically immediate (so initial load is longer but paging is on the fly, and the other is where independate ajax calls are made based on the option from the user). Which is considered best practise all round (loading, SEO, user experience).

Some references to good material or tutorials will be great!

Comment: As an aside, Google *can* crawl Ajax applications: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

Just to question a): It's not fully true that you won't have those links any more because as you supposed correctly, there are some users without JS enabled and some crawlers like Google. So links like "products.php?page=2" will surely survive the next few years.
But here is a possibility to combine SEO/users without JS and an AJAX possibility for those who have enabled it:

```html
<a href="products.php?page=2" onclick="loadPage('products.php',2);return false;">
 Next Page
</a>
```

EDIT: You also could run another PHP script on `onlclick`, maybe `loadProductsFrom('get_products.php', 2);` whereby the  function should load the JSON product-objects from the server similar to James Smiths answer but via AJAX and show them to the user. This would probably decrease traffic and download time but additionally cause some (or some more) overhead. So in this case the benefits for the users are obvious.

Comment: So effectively I will run the same script irrespective if the user has JS on or not. But what would then be the benefit of doing it the ajax way? I mean i might as well then just stick to the php way :P

Comment: Yes, it's as I said because not everybody (especially crawlers) makes use of JS. And those who don't.. what do you want to do with them if not the old-fashioned way? Ehm.. the benefits are all for the users, they will not need a page refresh, that's cool :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to load all your data in a javascript object for e.g:

```php
$strSql = "Select * from products";
$objResult = mysql_query($strSql);
$arrData = array();
while($objRow = mysql_fetch_array($objResult)){
 $objData = new stdClass();
 $objData->name = $objRow['name'];
 /* add more data here */
 $arrData[] = $objData;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var arrData =  <?php echo json_encode($arrData); ?> 
</script>
```

Now you can pass this arrData to any jquery pagination plugin and it will take care of all the pagination work for you, since the data is in compressed form, load time will  as well so your page will have a better search engine visibility..
hope this helps..